# Can I add two VALUES to a dictionary from user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I keep getting an error when I run this functions. Everything goes through and then it shows this error. I have tried adding .items() to the end when I print the dictionary and still throws this error.

CLARIFICATION just realized. Not getting any type errors or anything. It prints fine but when doesn't add the second variable to the dictionary. Instead it prints this..

{'Frappe': ('small', function type_of_milk at 0x000002BE2BCD2F78>)}

```
def order():
    ready_to_order = True
    while ready_to_order != False:
        ordering_q = input(
            """Do you know what you would like to order or do you need to see the menu?
                [M]enu or [R]eady to order or [Q]uit:   """)

        if ordering_q.upper() == "Q":
            sys.exit()
        elif ordering_q.upper() == "M":
            print(Menu())
        elif ordering_q.upper() == "R":
            ready_to_order = False
        else:
            print("Please enter valid letters only, try again.")
    print(" ")
    print(" ")

    add_cart = True
    while add_cart != False:
        order1 = input("What would you like to order?")
        if order1.upper() == "Done":
            add_cart = False
        elif order1 == 'a1':
            print("Frappe added to cart")
            global total_order
            total_order += 3
            drink_size()
            type_of_milk()
            order_dict['Frappe'] = (drink_sizes, type_of_milk)
            add_cart = False

    print(order_dict)
```

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: This `if order1.upper() == "Done"` looks fishy, it's never `True`

Comment: Where's your error? I'm not yet clarified what you asked here

Comment: I just edited the question. I am actually not getting any error, its just not printing out correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
    order_dict['Frappe'] = (drink_sizes, type_of_milk)
```

is adding the function `type_of_milk` to your dict, which is why you see `function type_of_milk at 0x000002BE2BCD2F78>` when you print the dict out.  Maybe you meant to say `type_of_milk()`?